# XE6 - XSLProd unit missing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I've just did a migration from XE3 to XE6. 
Now I'm stuck with compile error [dcc32 Fatal Error] e.pas(6): F1026 File not found: 'XSLProd.dcu'. On XE3 this unit is under the path `Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\source\internet`.

But under the same folder on XE6 there is no unit named like that. 
I've search the whole folder for **XslProd**.pas file and the result was 0.

Does anybody know what happend to this unit - I guess there is a chance that this unit was removed some version prior to XE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unit was removed in XE5. The classes that it contained are not to be found in any other unit in the source folder so one can only conclude that, either:

- Embarcadero decided to remove the unit from the product for some reason, or
- The unit was somehow removed by accident.

My guess is that the former is the case, that the unit was removed intentionally. And that the reason for doing so related to the development of the new mobile platforms.

Comment: Why does it show on both [xe5 unit scope](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Unit_Scope_Names) and [xe6 unit scope](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Unit_Scope_Names)?

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca Because the documentation is wrong. It's not there. It really has gone. Did you check? It's easy enough to do a search to confirm that is the case.

Comment: Fair enough. Answer deleted. :)

Comment: I can confirm that it isn't there in XE5 either. On older program versions such as RAD Studio 2009, it was located in `\source\win32`. (I only use C++ Builder but there shouldn't be any difference)

Comment: I did some research ... in XE5 the XSLProd.pas file is missing BUT there are still some other files "left" XMLBrokr, xmlutil, Xmlxform - in XE6 this files are not present. I guess Embarcadero is doing step-by-step cleaning (which I don't like!).

Comment: In any case I guess it's time to find a different library. I wonder why this is at -1 though.

Comment: I don't quite understand the -1 either. You get a +1 from me. <g>